# How can I resolve an R12 (Exit timeout) launching with Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, bots

I am using Heroku to host a bot that I have been working on, the code itself works perfectly from when I launch it locally. However, I updated the bot yesterday adding some new functionality, and I am receiving this error code when checking the logs:

```
2021-08-29T13:42:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-08-29T13:43:05.090490+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 30 seconds of SIGTERM
2021-08-29T13:43:05.095578+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2021-08-29T13:43:05.174771+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-08-29T13:56:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ty.unsworth@gmail.com
2021-08-29T13:56:24.413396+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5ff2d18b by user ty.unsworth@gmail.com
2021-08-29T13:56:24.413396+00:00 app[api]: Release v39 created by user ty.unsworth@gmail.com
2021-08-29T13:56:26.596593+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2021-08-29T13:56:26.610525+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-08-29T13:56:27.284912+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-08-29T13:56:29.770892+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python WagonCounterBot.py`
2021-08-29T13:56:30.497452+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-08-29T13:56:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-08-29T13:56:57.473450+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 30 seconds of SIGTERM
2021-08-29T13:56:57.481783+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2021-08-29T13:56:57.535059+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I think this error may be caused by the new functionality I added:

```
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    """
    Looks for when a member calls 'bhwagon', and after 24 minutes, sends them a message
    :param message: the message sent by the user
    :return: a DM to the user letting them know their cooldown ended
    """
    channel = client.get_channel(int(WAGON_CHANNEL))  # sets the

    if message.content.startswith("bhwagon"):
        channel = message.channel
        await cool_down_ended(message)


async def cool_down_ended(message):
    """
    Sends the author of the message a personal DM 24 minutes after they type 'bhwagon' in the guild
    :param message: is the message the author sent
    :return: a message to the author
    """
    time.sleep(1440)  # sets a time for 24 minutes = 1440 seconds

    await message.author.send("Your wagon steal timer is up  time for another materials run!")
```

So I think I understand this error to be that Heroku doesn't allow functions to delay themselves for more than 30 seconds? Which conflicts with *cool_down_ended(message)* that delays for 24 minutes.
Would there be any easy way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use `time.sleep` in asynchronous code, it blocks entire thread. Use `await asyncio.sleep(delay)` instead.
2. This is the code to handle SIGTERM from Heroku (you can add it before `client.run` call)

```py
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *_: client.loop.create_task(client.close()))
```